# Infer a type of sibling in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to achieve this in Typescript

```
const configuration: ResolveDeclaration = {
 deps: [Foo, Bar, Baz],
 resolveFn: (foo, bar, baz) => {} //<== foo, bar, baz has a type inherited in `deps` property accordingly
}
```

I tried this approach:

```
export interface ResolvableLiteral<D extends readonly Injectable[]> {
  deps: D;
  resolveFn: (...args: D) => any;
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work, as it doesn't infer passed values, but treat it as `Injectable[]`

Update:

Later on this configuration will be used this way:

```
const injectables = configuration.deps.map((token) => this.injector.get(token))
return configuration.resolveFn(...injectables)
```

So in `resolveFn` I want to get types of dependencies which I asked from dependency injector.

Comment: do you want to pass the objects in `deps` property, or only specify a list of types?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, can you explain why you want to do this? And why using 3 generic types doesn't work?

Comment: This is a kind of a pattern for Dependency Injection in Angular. For regular cases, angular uses decorators based annotation and some under the hood magic. But for unusual cases, especially when decorators could not be used they ask user to define a set of DI tokens. 

This is a piece of code from `@uirouter/angular` I could not change it, but if found for myself this pattern is very error-prone, because you always have to keep in think parameters and deps.

Comment: updated a question